# UBound function doesn't work when passing a Named Range as Variant

Tags: arrays, vba, variant

`MyArray` is a `(100 row x 1 column)` named range containing integers.

This doesn't work:

```
Function myFunc(MyArray As Variant)

myFunc = UBound(MyArray)
```

Nor does this:

```
Function myFunc(MyArray As Variant)

myFunc = UBound(MyArray, 1)
```

I'm sure this is a rather basic error, but I've done a fair amount of Googling and failed to work out the answer for myself. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're passing a variant array, not a Range object.  The function accepts a `variant` data type, which can be anything.  In order to ensure it's an array, pass the `.Value`

```
Sub Test()

Debug.Print myFunc(Range("A1:A50").Value)

End Sub

Function myFunc(MyArray As Variant)

myFunc = UBound(MyArray, 1)

End Function
```